# How to iterate on datatype to get associated values?

Tags: python, hdf5

I am currently discovering HDf5 library n Python and I have some problem. I have a dataset with this layout:

```
GROUP "GROUP1" {
                  DATASET "DATASET1" {
                     DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
                        H5T_STD_I64LE "DATATYPE1";
                        H5T_STD_I64LE "DATATYPE2";
                        H5T_STD_I64LE "DATATYPE3";
                     }
                     DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 3 ) / ( 3 ) }
                     DATA {
                     (0): {
                           1,
                           2,
                           3
```

I am trying to iterate in dataset to get the values associated to each datatype and copying them in a text file. (For example, "1" is the associated value to "DATATYPE1".) This following script does work:

```
new_file  = open('newfile.txt', 'a') 
for i in range(len(dataset[...])):
 new_file.write('Ligne '+ str(i)+" "+":"+" ") 
   for j in range(len(dataset[i,...])):
     new_file.write(str(dataset[i][j]) + "\n")
```

But it is not this clean... So I tried to get values by calling the datatypes by name. The closest script I found is the following:

```
for attribute in group.attrs:
    print group.attrs[attribute]
```

Unfortunately, despite my tries it does not work on datatype :

Checking datatypes leads to dataset

```
   for data.dtype in dataset.dtype:
#then print datatypes
       print dataset.dtype[data.dtype
```

**The backing error message is "numpy.dtype' object is not iterable".** 
Do you please have any idea how to process? I hope my question is clear.

Comment: We actually prefer that posters not put extra verbiage like greetings and "thanks in advance" in their questions.

Comment: You should use one of the HDF5 modules to access this file with Python: h5py and pytables are the most common.

Comment: Okay sorry about that.
 I actually use 'import h5py'.

Answer (score 0):

Without your data it's hard to offer specific solutions. Here is a very simple example that mimics your data schema using pytables (& numpy). First it creates the HDF5 file, with table named **DATASET1** under group **GROUP1**. **DATASET1** has 3 int values in each row named: DATATYPE1, DATATYPE2, and DATATYPE3. The `ds1.append()` function adds rows of data to the table (1 row at a time).
After the data is created, `walk_nodes()` is used to traverse the HDF5 file structure and print node names and dtypes for tables.

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np

with tb.open_file("SO_56545586.h5", mode = "w") as h5f:

    ds1 = h5f.create_table('/GROUP1', 'DATASET1', 
                           description=np.dtype([('DATATYPE1', int),('DATATYPE2', int),('DATATYPE3', int)]), 
                           createparents=True)
    for row in range(5) :
        row_vals = [ (row, row+1, row*2), ]
        ds1.append(row_vals)

## This section walks the file strcuture (groups and datasets), printing node names and dtype for tables:

    for this_node in h5f.walk_nodes('/'):
        print (this_node)
        if isinstance(this_node, tb.Table) :
            print (this_node.dtype)
```

Note: **do not use** `mode = "w"` when you open an existing file. It will create a new file (overwrite the existing file). Use `mode = "a"` or `mode = "r+"` if you need to append data, or `mode = "r"` if you only need to read the data.

Comment: Than you for your answer. It seems to work for me! I finally found another method that I will explain below before to close topic.

Answer (score 0):

To complete solution added by kcw78 I also found this script which also work. Because I can't iterate over dataset, I copied dataset into a new array :

```
dataset = file['path_to_dataset']

data = np.array(dataset) # Create a new array filled with dataset values as numpy.
print(data)  

ls_column = list(data.dtype.names) # Get a list with datatypes associated to each data values.
print(ls_column) # Show layout of datatypes associated to each previous data values. 

# Create an array filled with same datatypes rather than same subcases. 
for col in ls_column: 

    k = data[col] # example : k=data['DATATYPE1'], k=data['DATATYPE2']  
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Arnaud, OK, I see you are using h5py. 
I don't understand what you mean by "*I can't iterate over dataset*". You can iterate over rows, or columns/fields. 
Here is an example to demonstrate with h5py.

It shows 4 ways to extract data from the dataset, the last one iterates):

1. Read the entire HDF5 dataset to a np array
2. Then read 1 column from that array to another array
3. Read 1 column from the HDF5 dataset as an array
4. Loop thru HDF5 dataset columns and read 1 at a time as an array

Note that the return from `.dtype.names` is iterable. You don't need to create a list (unless you need it for other purposes). Also, HDF5 supports mixed types in datasets, so you can get a dtype with int, float, and string values (it will be a record array).

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

with h5py.File("SO_56545586.h5", "w") as h5f:

    # create empty dataset 'DATASET1' in group '/GROUP1'
    # dyte argument defines names and types
    ds1 = h5f.create_dataset('/GROUP1/DATASET1', (10,), 
              dtype=np.dtype([('DATATYPE1', int),('DATATYPE2', int),('DATATYPE3', int)]) )

    for row in range(5) :  # load some arbitrary data into the dataset
        row_vals = [ (row, row+1, row*2), ]
        ds1[row] = row_vals

    # to read the entire dataset as an array
    ds1_arr = h5f['/GROUP1/DATASET1'][:] 
    print (ds1_arr.dtype) 

    # to read 1 column from ds1_arr as an array
    ds1_col1 = ds1_arr[:]['DATATYPE1'] 
    print ('for DATATYPE1 from ds1_arr, dtype=',ds1_col1.dtype)

    # to read 1 HDF5 dataset column as an array
    ds1_col1 = h5f['/GROUP1/DATASET1'][:,'DATATYPE1'] 
    print ('for DATATYPE1 from HDF5, dtype=',ds1_col1.dtype)

    # to loop thru HDF5 dataset columns and read 1 at a time as an array
    for col in h5f['/GROUP1/DATASET1'].dtype.names :
        print ('for ', col, ', dtype=',h5f['/GROUP1/DATASET1'][col].dtype) 
        col_arr = h5f['/GROUP1/DATASET1'][col][:]
        print (col_arr.shape)
```